# Designing an interface where only some implementations require IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net

You are designing an interface `IFoo`

```
public interface IFoo
{
   void Bar();
}
```

Let's say there are five implementations of this interface. Two of those implementations should also implement `IDisposable` as they use unmanaged resources. From a caller's perspective, it would be easiest if `IFoo` implemented `IDisposable` so any `IFoo` can be wrapped in a `using` block, but of course some of the implementations would then be littered with empty `Dispose()` methods. Just curious are there other ways of doing this?

Comment: If the caller only knows about the `IFoo`, and some implementations of `IFoo` should be disposed, `IFoo` should inherit `IDisposable`.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that in my question, was just curious about any other approaches to the problem to avoid redundant implementations of IDisposable in concrete classes that didn't need it.

Comment: the only other option is to check wether the object implements `IDisposable` on the caller side, see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect I'd simply demand `IDisposable()` - a no-op `Dispose()` isn't a big overhead.

If you can't be sure whether it is disposable, the following is pretty effective:

```
var mightBeDisposable = GetBlah();
using(mightBeDisposable as IDisposable)
{
   // etc
}
```

Comment: Because if "as" fails it returns null instead of throwing an exception and so will always enter the using block right?

Comment: @Peter correct; and `using` already includes (in the spec) a `null` check, so only attempts to call `.Dispose()` in the case that `mightBeDisposable` turned out to be `IDisposable` (and hence a non-null value was observed)

Comment: Got it, section 8.13 "if (resource != null) (IDisposable)resource).Dispose();"

Comment: This pattern is also shown in More Effective C# p.33...

Answer (score 3):

There are precedents in the .NET Framework for interfaces that implement `IDisposable` - for example `IComponent`, `IDataReader`.

This seems a reasonable pattern when you expect most implementations to require disposal.

Comment: Good point. User expectations.

Answer (score 2):

Although objects that implement interfaces generally promise abilities or characteristics that are not common in objects without those interfaces, and although `IDisposable` is an interface, the fact that an object implements `IDisposable` doesn't promise any ability or characteristic that would be lacking in objects which do not.  Instead, the fact that an object implements `IDisposable` implies that it *lacks* a characteristic common in objects that don't implement it: the ability for anyone who acquires or holds a reference abandon it without regard for whether the object can or should be cleaned up first.

If code which uses a particular interface type will generally not be the last thing to hold a reference, then there's no need for the interface to implement `IDisposable`.  Even if some implementations cannot be safely abandoned, that won't matter to any users of an instance other than the last one that holds a reference.  If that user is generally going to know more about the specific type than is implied by the interface, the user will know whether the object needs cleanup whether or not the interface indicates it.

On the other hand, if the last user of an object will generally not know anything about it other than the fact that it implements some interface, then that interface should inherit `IDisposable` even (perhaps especially!) if only a tiny fraction of implementations will need cleanup.  Consider the case of `IEnumerable` versus `IEnumerable<T>`.  Any code which calls `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` will receive what is likely to be the only reference anywhere in the universe to an object which implements `IDisposable`.  As such, that code assumes the responsibility for ensuring that `Dispose` gets called on that reference.  Any code which calls `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` and neither calls `Dispose` on the returned value nor gives it to other code that promises to do so, is broken.

The type returned by non-generic `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` does not implement `IDisposable`.  That would on the fact of it seem to suggest that code which calls `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` does not have a responsibility to dispose it.  Unfortunately, such implication is incorrect.  Code which calls `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` has a responsibility to ensure that if the particular instance returned implements `IDisposable`, then its `Dispose` method must be called.  Code which does not uphold that responsibility is no less broken than code which fails to dispose the return from `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`.   The failure of the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` return type (i.e. `IEnumerator`) to to implement `IDisposable` does not eliminate caller's responsibility for cleaning up the returned object.  It merely makes such responsibility more burdensome to carry out, and increases the probability that code will fail to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a disposable version of your interface which better shows your intent:

```
public interface IDisposableFoo : IFoo, IDisposable
{
}
```

Any class inheriting this interface could still be treated as an IFoo. An issue you may have is the need to check if your IFoo object is a disposable version before treating as such however this is fairly easy.

Comment: The implementations of this interface that don't require IDisposable will still need to implement it.

Comment: @Peter Kelly - then use the IFoo interface instead for those implementations. This option is just a way of explicitly showing in code that there is a disposable option

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding some code to your calling site, you can just do the following:

```
IFoo foo = GetMeSomeFoo();

foo.UseFoo();

var disposableFoo = foo as IDisposable;
if (disposableFoo != null)
    disposableFoo.Dispose();
```

Not pretty, but doesn't pollute your interface. Doesn't ensure that the caller will do all this stuff, either.

**EDIT:** as Hans Passant pointed out, it's essentially equal to

```
IFoo foo = GetMeSomeFoo();
using (foo as IDisposable) {
    foo.UseFoo();
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you're not using the using keyword

Comment: @Hans Passant: neat, I didn't know that `using` behaves that way with `null` values, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would not force IFoo to implement IDisposable as it is against SOLID.
You can derive a IDisposableFoo from IFoo if you like or you can make a check (or even custom method that wraps a IFoo into a DisposableAdapter and checks for IDisposable) if you need it.

```
class DisposableAdapter : IDisposable, IFoo
{
   IFoo _obj;
   public DisposableAdapter(IFoo obj)
   {
      _obj = obj;
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      if (_obj is IDisposable)
        ((IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
   }     

   // copy IFoos implementations from obj

}
```

using

```
using(var foo = new DisposableAdapter(myFoo)) //... use foo just as you had myFoo
```

Comment: Which SOLID guideline do you argue it violates?

Comment: I would argue for some combination of the SRP and the ISP - uncle Bob calls it "Interface Pollution". Why force some Foos to implement empty methods?

Answer (score 0):

You either need 2 interfaces one that implements IDisposable and one that doesn't - `IFoo` and `IDisposableFoo` or just make `IFoo` disposable.

Theres no harm in having some empty implementations of `IDisposable`. Given you already have some which require dispose it seems a likely use case.